# Python Selenium deal with an angucomplete element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, input

I have a selenium task at hand and the input element I'm trying to send_keys gives me an ElementNotInteractableException. figured that my input resides in an angucomplete element. well, I'm not new to selenium but can't find a solution for this so appreciate any idea or instruction for this

```html
<angucomplete placeholder="" searchfields="" pause="400" set-focus="tpFocus" selectedobject="tpSelected" titlefield="label" inputclass="form-control form-control-small" matchclass="highlight" api="tpApi" disable="disableSearchBox" stockdetails="stockdetails"
  class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <div class="tp-re angucomplete-holder tp-width">
    <div id="fulltextContainer" style="display: none" class="symbol-info tp-etc">
    </div>
    <input id="txt_search" class="search-box tp-co-1 tp-pa-rl-5 tp-re tp-bo-bo" type="text" placeholder="" onmouseup="this.select();" autocomplete="off" />
    <div id="auto-list-container" class="auto-list-container tp-bg-2 tp-co-1 tp-bo-4 tp-bo tp-width angucomplete-dropdown" style="min-width: 300px; display: none">
      <div style="display: none" id="loading" class="tp-h-35 tp-pa-rl-10 angucomplete-searching"></div>
      <div style="display: none" id="norecord" class="tp-35 tp-pa-rl-10 angucomplete-searching"></div>
      <div id="list_dropdown">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</angucomplete>
```

Comment: would it be possible to share the website that does this?

Comment: actually this is a stock broker website and needs signup, etc

Comment: Can you include the html code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript to set the value attribute of the input field.
For example:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("input")
value = "The text you want to put"
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{}')".format(value), elem)
```